# I lost bitcoins in mtgox, I don't know why and how

Tags: mtgox

I have a mtgox without verification yet, opened in June of 2013, and recently I put in some 26btcs in December.
I begin to operate buying and selling and in January 8, I had 26,03 btcs and now I see that January 8, there were 3 withdrawals in seconds to a btc account, first one for 1 btc, the second one for 5 btcs, and the last one for 20 btcs.

I think a lot possibilities, first one is that somebody stole me, but I don't understand how it is possible to do a withdrawal without verification, because mtgox inform that is not possible without verification, and after that, the limit begins in 1 btc per day. So I don't understand anything.

Other possibility is mtgox took my btc until I verify the account, but it is very rare mtgox  take my btc in three times and cost me 0, 0001 btd each one. So I don't believe a lot in that possibility.

So, anyone are able to tell me something to help me…

Comment: Thanks for answer. But my account did not let me to do withdrawals because I have short balance and I tried, and mtgox system inform me that I need to verify. So I think I am not AML and my account is not too old. So after tell u this what do you think that happen with my account? Thanks for all

Comment: My bitcoins are stuck too, all I want to do is get my bitcoins the hell out of mt gox but I tried to withdraw one and it 'disappeared'...didn't even appear on the block chain. Mt gox has not responded to any of my support tickets. Basically my life is ruined, no college for me.

Comment: This isn't an answer, should be a comment.

Answer (score 0):

Contact mtgox support so they can review your transactions, if you are not verified and you can not do withdrawals then it is a problem if their system so the must refund you.

But probably that's not the case, you should check that the registered email is your email if everything is as it was when you left the account, probably a hacker got access to your email then to mtgox and changed your account settings to withdraw without your consent.

Answer (score 0):

afaik old accounts are not automatically AML flagged, only the most recent accounts are all required to verify before they can deposit or withdraw, old accounts can still withdraw btcs until they ( possibly ) get aml flagged some day and need to verify.

an account opened in  june 2013 is possibly old enough to still be allowed to withdraw bitcoins

mtgox does NOT "take your btc until you verify", never, ever

also :

- you should have opened a support ticket
- if you did and your story is true, give the ticket number, the mtgox support will have a look at it
- you should secure your mtgox account with a one time password ( OTP ) using a yubikey, otpcard, or at the very least google auth, particularly if you use windows shitty OS ( installing a keylogger on your windows computer is pretty easy for thousands of good crackers )
- in many cases, people reporting this kind of story had an intelligent friend or girlfriend using an opened session to empty the account of the btcs

Comment: Thanks for answer. But my account did not let me to do withdrawals because I have short balance and I tried, and mtgox system inform me that I need to verify. So I think I am not AML and my account is not too old. So after tell u this what do you think that happen with my account? Thanks for all

Comment: i think your account is old enough to be allowed to withdraw btcs

Comment: Thanks a lot other time. I checked when I opened account and it was opened April 6th of 2013,  but I did not make any deposit until January 1th of 2014. So I think that rules change in May 30 th in mtgox to not allowed withdraws without verification. So what do u think now with this information. It is very rare change rules for new customer only. And why I can not withdraw the rest of my bitcoins right now...

Comment: ok, your account is old enough to be allowed to withdraw btcs .

Answer (score 0):

"there were 3 withdrawals in seconds to a btc account, first one for 1 btc, the second one for 5 btcs, and the last one for 20 btcs."

I had this strange multi withdrawal process when my bitcoins were stolen from Mtgox. There were two small withdrawals followed by a final bigger withdrawal. I'd recommend that you check your email registered with that account. It should have received a transaction notification from Mt.Gox asking if you authorized this withdrawal.